# Testing element order in Selenium Webdriver with Elemental strings

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

To start of easily, I want Selenium Webdriver to check the order of elements. Our way of selecting the elements is almost always done with Xpath identifiers.

Check the following HTML code:

```
<html> 
<body>

<header>
This is the header
</header>

This is the body

<footer>
This is the footer
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

What I want, using Selenium Java Webdriver (and xpaths) to check if indeed the header comes first, and *then* the footer.

```
header = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header")) 
footer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//footer"))
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a `getLocation()` element on a webElement it will a point showing the containing the  top left-hand corner of the element.

Comparing the values should give you the desired effect. This is from the user perspective,

From the DOM perspective you can use more advanced [XPATH](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#axes)

e.g.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//header")).findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::footer"));
```

Comment: Can I also turn that Footer in your DOM perspective in a String? Something in the line of: 

driver.findElement(By.xpath(AAA)).findElement(By.xpath("./following-sibling::('" + BBB + "')"));

How would that look?